# Custom terser-webpack-plugin cache invalidation in Webpack 4

Tags: webpack, terser

I am upgrading a large app from Webpack v3 to v4.

With Webpack 3, we had a custom post-Webpack mechanism for UglifyJS.  It stored post-processed JS files in a given directory for 24 hours, and its filename was a hash generated from its content.

Now, we have replaced our post-Webpack Uglify step with the built-in TerserJS plugin.  I would like to replicate the above caching feature.

I have tried reading the docs, but they are sparse on this subject: https://webpack.js.org/plugins/terser-webpack-plugin/#cache

The docs fail to mention for how long the files will be cached, or how they will be invalidated.

If someone could point me in the right direction, that would be much appreciated.